# iOS Upload Photo in Parts

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, nsurlconnection

Let's say I want to preserve the full resolution of a photo on the iPhone, and then upload it to a web service for storing. Quality is critical. Unfortunately, the size of a 3200x2400 photo taken with the iPhone camera is approximately 10-12MB for a PNG, and 1-3MB for a JPG (as of my latest tests).

Here we have a dilemma. On a 3G connection, a 12MB upload is an eternity (relatively speaking, of course). So I've explored a few options, including streams/chunking and background uploading. Still, it's not ideal. <strike>I'd like the upload to be as fast as possible.</strike> See edit.

So my question is this: would it be possible to split an image into separate data chunks, upload them all concurrently using multiple asynchronous connections, and then re-assemble them server side? Does an implementation exist for this?

**EDIT**: So speed is capped by bandwidth as has been discussed in the comments. But there are other uses for chunking/splitting that I would like to explore. So the question still stands.

Comment: What would be the benefit to split the image into separate data chunks? The main "problem" still exists - your limited upload bandwidth. Basically the answer to your question is `YES` it would be possible but imho it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Good point. I guess I lost my brain. However there are other uses IMO to splitting them. Namely, resuming uploads if they fail. I suppose JPEG would help with size.. maybe compressing as zip. Are there no benefits at all to splitting files then?

Comment: Yes, there are benefits of splitting them as you mentioned - but again, the main problem persists. By the way - zipping a JPEG brings you basically no benefits at all - the file size stays the same ;)

Comment: I should have said jpg OR zip, as obviously jpg is already in compressed format :P I suppose I just don't want to have a connection open that is transferring 12MB on a choppy 3G connection. So yes even though speed is capped by bandwidth, there are other reasons for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is actually split the image into several pieces, and upload each, then reassemble later.
I guess a benefit of that would be getting a partial image on failed connection, then continuing uploading the remaining pieces afterwards.